# Got some errors after update Xcode 7 with Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Today i updated my xcode to version 7 with swift 2.0.
Then i got so many errors in my production app, But i already fixed most of it by myself.

The problem is some of it i don't know how to fix.
So the images below are errors that i could not fix it myself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If anyone knows how to fix it please help.
Thanks!

Comment: First error says the method is gone and suggests you to use another one.
To fix all the other errors you should check the new API. Mainly, try to rewrite those lines and be careful about what methods take or return. You'll see what's wrong.

Comment: I tried to fix the first one by URLBy appending path but got so many errors instead on that function then i decided to roll back to the old one for now.

Answer (score 1):

As explain in the comment, you simply have to rewrite those lines by checking the method signature :

1.

```
// Use the NSURL methods instead of String ones
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsFolder).URLByAppendingPathComponent("baseDeck.sqlite").path!
```

2.

```
// Make sure the productId is a String
request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: [productId])
```

3.

```
// Be careful to parameters, they are optionals
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   //...
}
```

4.

```
// Be careful too, the invalidProductIdentifiers method return an array of string whereas the response.products an array of SKProduct
let products = responses.products.filter { productIndentifiers.contains($0.productIdentifier) }
```

I hope it'll help you.